# If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random on the probability space $(\Omega , F, P)$, show that $U$ and $V$ are also discrete random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random on the probability space $(\Omega , F, P)$, show that $U$ and $V$ are also discrete random variables where $$U(\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$$
$$ V(\omega) = X(\omega)Y(\omega)$$

Answer (score 2):

If $E,E'$ are events with $\Pr(E)=1=\Pr(E')$ then: $$\Pr(E\cap E')=\Pr(E)+\Pr(E')-\Pr(E\cup E')=1+1-1=1\tag1$$

Countable sets $A,B$ exist with $\Pr(X\in A)=1=\Pr(Y\in B)$.

Then $(1)$ tells us that $$\Pr(X\in A\wedge Y\in B)=1$$ A consequence of this is:$$\Pr(X+Y\in A+B)=1$$ This for $A+B:=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ which is a a countable set.

Same procedure for $XY$.